# CompletionStage.thenCompose not executing serially

Tags: java, java-8, completable-future

I'm trying to use java 8 CompletionStages to execute 2 asynchronous method serially, so that the second is not executed if the first fails. But when I call thenCompose, the function passed in seems to get started before the previous function is complete (eg: the two function erroneously execute in parallel. Here is the code:

```
  public CompletionStage<Graph> create(Payload payload) {
    CompletionStage<BlobInfo> fileFuture = createFile(payload);
    CompletionStage<Entity> metadataFuture = createMetadata(payload);
    return fileFuture
        .thenCompose(ignore -> metadataFuture)
        .thenApply(entity ->
            buildFromEntity(objectMapper, entity));
  }

  public CompletionStage<BlobInfo> createFile(Payload payload) {
    return CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> {
      try {
        return
            storage.create(
                BlobInfo
                    .newBuilder(payload.bucket, payload.name)
                    .build(),
                payload.data.getBytes());
      } catch (StorageException e) {
        LOG.error("Failed to write to storage: " + e);
        throw new RequestHandlerException(StatusCode.SERVER_ERROR,
            "Failed to write to storage.");
      }
    });
  }


  public CompletionStage<Entity> createMetadata(Payload payload) {
    return CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> createSync(payload));
  }

  private Entity createMetadataSync(Payload payload) {
    Key key = keyFactory.newKey(payload.id);
    Entity.Builder entityBuilder = GraphPayload.buildEntityFromGraph(payload, key);
    Entity entity = entityBuilder.build();
    LOG.error("Metadata.createSync");

    try {
      datastore.add(entity);
    } catch (DatastoreException e) {
      LOG.error("Failed to write initial metadata: " + e);
      throw new RequestHandlerException(StatusCode.SERVER_ERROR,
          "Failed to write initial metadata.");
    }
    return entity;
  }
```

OUTPUT:

```
16:57:47.530 [ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-3] ERROR com.spotify.nfgraphstore.store.FileStore - CreateFile
16:57:47.530 [ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-2] ERROR com.spotify.nfgraphstore.store.MetadataStore - Metadata.createSync
16:57:47.530 [ForkJoinPool.commonPool-worker-3] ERROR com.spotify.nfgraphstore.store.FileStore - Failed to write initial graph to storage: com.google.cloud.storage.StorageException: X
```

The logged output demonstrates that Metadata.createSync is getting executed before the Storage exception gets thrown. This conclusion is also born out by a test (not shown) which is supposed to show zero interactions with the metadata DB if the write to the file storage DB fails. That test sometimes fails, suggesting a race condition.

So I'm left thinking thenCompose does not guarantee serial execution. But everything I've read in the java docs suggests execution should be serial: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CompletionStage.html#thenCompose-java.util.function.Function-

Does anyone know why execution is not guaranteed to be serial, or recommend other functions that might work more as I've intended?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The call to `createMetadata` launches the task immediately, because it is not called as part of the lambda expression passed to `thenCompose`.

Perhaps you meant to do this:

```
.thenCompose(ignore -> createMetadata(payload))
```

Comment: …or just `thenApplyAsync(ignore -> createSync(payload));`, as there is no reason to wrap the operation into another `CompletableFuture`.

Comment: Thanks. That answer seems to fix the problem. I don't understand why though. I added more debug statements, and the line which creates the metadata future is definitely not causing createMetadataSync to get invoked. So it must be getting called immediately by thenCompose. Why would thenCompose invoke the completion stage before the previous stage has finished?

Comment: Thanks for the extra answer Holger. I've verified that works too.

Comment: The only thing that `thenCompose` invokes is the `ignore -> metadataFuture` lambda.  Because `metadataFuture` was generated outside of this lambda, it will have started long before `thenCompose` has even seen it.